# How to make pytest return failure if a minimum number of tests is not run?

Tags: python, pytest

As tests can be enabled or disabled automatically based on existing environment there is always the risk that something in CI is changed that makes pytest skip tests when they were not supposed to.

If I could define a minimum number of tests, or maybe even a fixed number of expected tests in an environment variable I could prevent accidents where CI passes just because tests were skipped.

Most of the time pytest is called by tox, which is also used in development environments. This means that the expected number of tests must be defined in CI config (like `.travis.yml`), because this is the only place which is specific to CI.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom hook impl and count the amount of passed tests. After the test run finishes, check the counter and exit with a custom exit code if the amount of tests passed was too low. Example: add the code to your `conftest.py`:

```
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--minpass', type=int, default=0, help='minimum amount of tests to pass')


def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    session.count_passed = 0


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    result = outcome.get_result()

    if result.when == 'call' and result.passed:
        item.session.count_passed += 1


def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    min_passed = session.config.getoption('minpass')
    if session.count_passed < min_passed:
        session.exitstatus = 127
        reporter = session.config.pluginmanager.get_plugin('terminalreporter')
        reporter.section('Session errors', sep='-', red=True, bold=True)
        reporter.line(f'Not enough successful tests - expected at least {min_passed} to pass, passed {session.count_passed}')
```

This adds a new command line option `--minpass` that expects a minimal amount of tests required for the run to succeed; the default value is zero so it shouldn't affect any existing suites if not provided. `session.exitstatus = 127` sets the custom exit code; change it to whatever code you need. The `pytest_sessionfinish` hook uses the terminal reporter to display the error in a custom section; change the output to whatever format you need.

A sample execution with at least one test to pass yields:

```
$ pytest --minpass 1
======================================= test session starts ========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-5.3.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /home/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-59116898
plugins: mock-1.11.0, xdist-1.29.0, asyncio-0.10.0, forked-1.0.2, cov-2.8.1, testinfra-3.2.0
collected 1 item                                                                                   

test_spam.py s                                                                               [100%]
------------------------------------------ Session errors ------------------------------------------
Not enough successful tests - expected at least 1 to pass, passed 0


======================================== 1 skipped in 0.01s ========================================
$ echo $?
127
```

If you want to support the environment variables, adapt the `pytest_sessionfinish` hook impl with e.g.

```
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    min_passed = session.config.getoption('minpass') or int(os.environ.get('PYTEST_MINPASS', '0'))
    ...
```

and set the `PYTEST_MINPASS` environment variable to turn on the check.

Comment: Thanks, this works really nice! I am wondering if it would make sense to add this to pytest-cov as it is related to it. I will see if that is desired and I will a PR if so.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to make the entire message red? Apparently the error itself is hard to spot on https://travis-ci.com/ansible/molecule/jobs/262180196#L412

Comment: Just found one deal-breaker: apparently that returns zero with pytest-xdist. It works fine without but when using xdist, always returns zero. It can easily be reproduced with somethign like `pytest -n2 -m "not foo"`. When using markers and xdist, the number of tests ends up being zero.

Comment: @sorin coloring the output using `terminalreporter` is easy, just add the `red=True` argument like I did in the section line, for example `reporter.line('hello world', red=True)`. The distributed case is tricky as `xdist` creates a separate session per each process or client, so the approach should be gathering results in each process, then pass them back via `execnet`, then combine. I will try to come up with an example and update the answer shortly.

Comment: No need to bother, I already found one, I will update it myself. Works really nice!